Can't find libcamera-v4l2 on apt on Raspberry PI 4
I have been trying to run the following command:
sudo apt install libcamera-v4l2

To no avail:
admin@RegularPi:~ $ sudo apt install libcamera-v4l2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libcamera-v4l2

As to follow the µStreamer Raspberry PI compatibility documentation.
Details:
uname -a: Linux RegularPi 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 16:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux
sudo apt update: (note: I have Tailscale installed.)
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Get:5 https://pkgs.tailscale.com/stable/debian bullseye InRelease
Fetched 6,578 B in 1s (4,761 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

I know my Raspberry PI repository is enabled (as indicated by the above update log), and libcamera-v4l2 exists, but apt search libcamera doesn't include it.

Here are my full logs for apt search libcamera: https://hst.sh/bivadiseyo.apache

You need to use the bookworm Raspberry PI distribution (reflashing, upgrading the OS, etc.), which includes the bookworm Debian repository, which contains libcamera-v4l2.
On this variant, libcamera-v4l2 should be an available package.
